# Radio button with text input and dropdown list for React Jsx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, radio-button, jsx

I am trying to implemented radio buttons in react. For each option of the radio button, it will have text input or dropdown as the input as well. I tried to use 'react-bootstrap/Form', however, it seems not allow me add input into the Form.check.

````
```<Form>
        {['radio'].map((type) => (
          <div key={`default-${type}`} className="mb-3">
            <Form.Check type={type} id={`${type}-1`} label={`Within miles`} />
            <Form.Check type={type} id={`${type}-2`} label={`Option`}>
              <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <InputGroup.Text >Enter option</InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup>
            </ Form.Check >
          </div>
        ))}
      </Form>```
````

I am wondering how could I achieve the radio button with the text and dropdown input in react. The screenshot is the style I would like to achieve. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You're mixing up two different input approaches. Have a `<select>` that updates state or, if the client adds their own option, have that update the state instead. Radio buttons have a specific purpose which are no use in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Isn't a <select> only works for the dropdown list of the within miles option? For my case, the user could only select one of the options between Within miles and Enter option (there are more options but I only list two here). In addition, for each option, there is a input attached to the option as well.